Slug of a child page is accessible with and without the parent slug in the URL
Consider I have two pages in WordPress, and I make one a child of the other
example.com/foo/
example.com/bar/ <-- set /foo/ as the parent
to end up with:
example.com/foo/bar/
After this is done, if I attempt to reach example.com/bar/
I would expect WordPress to automatically redirect this to example.com/foo/bar/.
I have a couple of client sites in which this does not occur. Instead, the child page can be accessed on its own.
Both example.com/bar/ and example.com/foo/bar/ are accessible. An edit made to one changes the other. They are the same page.
However, I noticed that there is a canonical link element being set on the child page that lists the proper full path.
So I have two questions:

Why is this probably happening?
What part of WordPress core is responsible for this redirect occurring.

Edit: I have yet to figure out why this is happening, but wrote the following function which seems to be working as a bandaid.
FYI I'm still very much a beginner when it comes to WordPress development, and have no idea if this aligns with best practice. I appreciate any constructive criticism.

/*
 * Prevent child pages from being reachable without the parent page slug
 * */

 add_action('parse_request', 'intercept_and_redirect_child_pages', 1);

 function intercept_and_redirect_child_pages($wp) {
     // Only run on front-end requests
     if (is_admin()) return;
 
     // Get the request path
     $path = trim($wp->request, '/');
 
     // If the path is empty, we're on the homepage, so no need to redirect
     if (empty($path)) return;
 
     // Split the path into segments
     $segments = explode('/', $path);
 
     // If there's only one segment, it might be a child page without its parent slug
     if (count($segments) === 1) {
         $potential_child_slug = $segments[0];
 
         // Query for pages with this slug
         $pages = get_posts(array(
             'name' => $potential_child_slug,
             'post_type' => 'page',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'numberposts' => 1,
         ));
 
         if (!empty($pages)) {
             $page = $pages[0];
 
             // Check if this page has a parent
             if ($page->post_parent) {

                // Ensure the correct permalink 
                 $correct_url = get_permalink($page->ID);
                 wp_safe_redirect($correct_url, 301);

                 exit;
             }
         }
     }
 }



More info might be needed. Can you please share the links to pages?

what additional information can I get for you? I would prefer to not post links to my client's site in here

I tried replicating your issue at my end but it's working normally. The child page is accessible only through /foo/bar. That's why needed to see it in live action to see what is wrong.

Try installing the Elementor plugin then test it again.

wordpress handle this using rewrite rules.
in fact worpdress does redirect /bar to /foo/bar by default but it's need rewrite rules to be configured correctly.
maybe some plugin or custom rules is interrupting the default rewrite rules.
try click on Save Changes in Settings > Permalink and see if auto redirect is fixed or not.


This does not work. I've tried that and many other things. Posting here was a last resort. I've got a solution working but I want to know why. These sites are my only clients that use the elementor plugin, I think this is the problem
